# jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery

Following ajax call is not working in Mozilla Firefox,alert is comming in succes function but ajax page is not hitting

```
  $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '../common/AjaxPage.aspx',               
                data: { action: 'SaveSafepurchase', SafeName: el('<%=txtSafeName.ClientID %>').value, SafeDuration: el('<%=ddlTimeFrame.ClientID %>').value, SafeDurText: $('#<%=ddlTimeFrame.ClientID %> :selected').text() },
                success: function () { alert("df"); },
                error: function (e) { alert(e); return false; },
                 cache: false
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../common/AjaxPage.aspx',
    data: {
        action: 'SaveSafepurchase',
        SafeName: el('<%=txtSafeName.ClientID %>').value,
        SafeDuration: el('<%=ddlTimeFrame.ClientID %>').value,
        SafeDurText: $('#<%=ddlTimeFrame.ClientID %> :selected').text()
    },
    success: function (alert("HI");)
        { },
    error: function (e)
        {
            alert(e);
            return false;
        },
    cache: false
});
```

Code formatting, use it, love it.

I think the issue here is you are passing a function into the argument of another function.

Change

```
success: function (alert("HI");){ },
```

To

```
success: function() { alert("Hi"); },
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the ajax call using Firebug with Firefox. If not, then use Net Panel of Firebug to see what happened during the request.

The success callback is invoked that is the request is considered succeed whenever the status code is 2xx or 304.